# Render AS3 Flash (swf) to video server-side

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, video, encoding

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done? Or a product?

I have a SWF timeline animation that grabs XML/images dynamically and then need to output/encode that as a video.

Comment: I guess it could be done using some sort of screen capture or screen sharing software.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Its very interesting for me too. Can you share please?

Comment: @Petr no, but it wasn't a very important project. Not important enough to implement something like Jonatan Hedborg suggested below (capturing each frame individually and then combining them into a video).

If you're looking for a manual solution try this (http://www.newgrounds.com/wiki/creator-resources/flash-resources/swivel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the functionality (in flash) to render each frame to a BitmapData-object, and then send that encoded as JPEG to a (local) service (either through URLLoader or via TCP/IP sockets) which saves them as images on file and then converts that into a movie once all frames are rendered.

EDIT: You can use a part of AS3 Core Lib ( https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib ) to convert a BitmapData into a JPEG file (in memory).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a FLV as output, you could use an FLV encoder like this: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/